# How to add options on an argument in pydev command line

Tags: python, command-line, pydev

I am trying to run my script with custom options like this:

```
#This  would print a help statement
main.py -h
```

However I am using eclipse to run pydev's command line, and I have to use a execfile() which runs the file yuo give it. But I am unable to pass an option since the execfile() thinks it is part of the file name.

Output from pydev

```
import sys; print('%s %s' % (sys.executable or sys.platform, sys.version))
PyDev console: starting.
C:\Python32\python.exe 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:29:02) [MSC v.1500 32    bit (Intel)]

execfile('C:\\Users\\212412120\\workspace\\parser_version1\\main.py -h')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
 File     "C:\Users\212412120\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.3.0.201508182223\pysrc\_  pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 11, in execfile
    stream = tokenize.open(file)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tokenize.py", line 344, in open
   buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:    'C:\\Users\\212412120\\workspace\\parser_version1\\main.py -h'
```

Answer (score 0):

[execfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) is not quite what you want for this task. If you are trying to do the equivalent to `$ python main.py -h`, then Right-Click on the main.py and choose Run As -> Python Script.

That runs with default settings, which does not include command line arguments. To add command line arguments, edit the Launch Configuration by going to *Run* menu -> *Run Configurations...*. Choose *Python Run* on the left and create or edit the launch configuration. You should end up at a screen like this:

[image: run config]

There is a lot more help on using PyDev here: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_root.html